# How do I get all jQuery-portlet data on a page?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a page containing so called portlets (jQuery). I want a button that opens up a dialog containing all portlet data (including the id of the column containing them).

So I want the dialog to look something like this:

---

col1:

portlet title: Title1

portlet content: The Content of Title1..

portlet title: Title2

portlet content: The Content of Title2..

col2:

portlet title: TIIIIITLE

portlet content: The Content of TIIIIITLE

portlet title: TIIIIITLE22121

portlet content: The Content of TIIIIITLE2212

---

or something like that. The important part is how to access the portlet data.

**EDIT:** I added this jquery (and some html below), which opens a dialog with the portlet data, only it's not doing what I want it to. If I have 2 portlets with title/content (a/1) & (b/2) and open the dialog, I get this: ab 12 ab 12. I want: a 1 b 2. The row below is the one that needs to be changed, I want to use the header/content of the current portlet in the each statement.

```
allContent += $(".portlet-header").text() + '\n' + $(".portlet-content").text() + '\n\n';
```

more new jQuery

```
$( "#dialog-form-html" ).dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                height: 600,
                width: 400,
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                    Cancel: function() {
                        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                    }
                },
                close: function() {
                }
            });

            $( "#get-html" )
            .button()
            .click(function() {
                var allContent = "";
                $(".portlet").each(function(){
                    allContent += $(".portlet-header").text() + '\n' + $(".portlet-content").text() + '\n\n';                        
                });                    
                $( "#dialog-form-html" ).text(allContent);
                $( "#dialog-form-html" ).dialog( "open" );
            });
```

jQuery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">


        $(function() {
            var title = $( "#title" ),
            content = $( "#content" ), column = $( "#column" ); 

            $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                height: 300,
                width: 350,
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                    "Add content": function() {                            
                        if(column.val()=='col1'){
                            $( "#col1" ).append($('<div class="portlet ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all">' +
                                '<div class="portlet-header ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">' +
                                '<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-minusthick"></span>' + title.val() + '</div>' +
                                '<div class="portlet-content">' + content.val() + '</div></div>'))
                            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                        }
                        else if(column.val()=='col2'){
                            $( "#col2" ).append($('<div class="portlet ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all">' +
                                '<div class="portlet-header ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">' +
                                '<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-minusthick"></span>' + title.val() + '</div>' +
                                '<div class="portlet-content">' + content.val() + '</div></div>'))
                            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                        }
                        else if(column.val()=='col3'){
                            $( "#col3" ).append($('<div class="portlet ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all">' +
                                '<div class="portlet-header ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">' +
                                '<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-minusthick"></span>' + title.val() + '</div>' +
                                '<div class="portlet-content">' + content.val() + '</div></div>'))
                            $( this ).dialog( "close" );                                
                        }
                        else if(column.val()=='col4'){
                            $( "#col4" ).append($('<div class="portlet ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all">' +
                                '<div class="portlet-header ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">' +
                                '<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-minusthick"></span>' + title.val() + '</div>' +
                                '<div class="portlet-content">' + content.val() + '</div></div>'))
                            $( this ).dialog( "close" );                                
                        }                            
                        else{
                            $( "#tempcol" ).append($('<div class="portlet ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all">' +
                                '<div class="portlet-header ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">' +
                                '<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-minusthick"></span>' + title.val() + '</div>' +
                                '<div class="portlet-content">' + content.val() + '</div></div>'))
                            $( this ).dialog( "close" );                                
                        } 
                    },
                    Cancel: function() {
                        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                    }
                },
                close: function() {
                    //test();
                }
            });

            $( "#add-content" )
            .button()
            .click(function() {
                $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog( "open" );
            });

            $( ".column" ).sortable({
                connectWith: ".column"
            });

            $( ".portlet" ).addClass( "ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all" )
            .find( ".portlet-header" )
            .addClass( "ui-widget-header ui-corner-all" )
            .prepend( "<span class='ui-icon ui-icon-minusthick'></span>")
            .end()
            .find( ".portlet-content" ); 

            $( ".column" ).disableSelection();

            $("#centered").on('click', ".portlet-header .ui-icon", function() {
                $( this ).toggleClass( "ui-icon-minusthick" ).toggleClass( "ui-icon-plusthick" );
                $( this ).parents( ".portlet:first" ).find( ".portlet-content" ).toggle();
            });
        });

    </script>
```

**EDIT:** I also added this html for the new dialog:

```
<div id="dialog-form-html" title="Copy html into email">
                <p>
                    test
                </p>
            </div>
```

HTML:

```
<body>

    <div id="centered">

        <div id="inset">
            <h1>HALLÅ EKONOMEN</h1>
            <div id="linear" style="padding: 20px"></div>
        </div>

        <div id="dialog-form" title="Create new user">
            <p class="validateTips">All form fields are required.</p>

            <form>
                <fieldset>
                    <label for="title">Title</label>
                    <input type="text" name="title" id="title" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
                    <label for="content">Content</label>
                    <input type="text" name="content" id="content" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
                    <label for="column">Column</label>
                    <select name="column" id="column" class="ui-spinner-down ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
                        <option value="col1">left sidebar</option>
                        <option value="col2">main</option>
                        <option value="col3">bottom left</option>
                        <option value="col4">bottom right</option>
                    </select>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>

        <button id="add-content" >Add Content</button>
        <div id="preview">
            <table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <!--sidebar-->
                        <td>
                            <div id="col1" class="column">
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <!--sidebar end-->   
                        <td>
                            <table>
                                <tbody>
                                    <!--main-->
                                    <tr>
                                        <div id="col2" class="column">
                                        </div>
                                    </tr>             
                                    <!--main end-->
                                    <!--bottom colums-->
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="border-left: 0px; border-bottom: 0px">
                                            <div id="col3" class="column">
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="border-right: 0px; border-bottom: 0px">
                                            <div id="col4" class="column">
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>                                    
                                    <!--bottom colums end-->
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </td>           
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            Trash column:<br /><br /><br />
            <div id="trashcol" class="column">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing my question was a bit difficult to understand, but just in case someone needs help with this in the future I'm gonna post an answer to my own question.

This jQuery will first find all the portlets in column 1 and for each one of these it will take out the text of the header div tag and the content div tag. This is done for all 4 columns. After all the portlet-text has been copied to the variable allContent, I set the dialog html (because I added some 
 to allContent) with html(allContent). This results in something like:

--Column 1-- 
header 1  : the content of portlet 1
header 2- : the content of portlet 2
--Column 2-- 
header 3  : the content of portlet 3
--Column 3--
(no portlets in column 3)
--Column 4-- 
header 4  : the content of portlet 4
header 5  : the content of portlet 5
header 6  : the content of portlet 6

**jQuery code:**

```
/*Open dialog containing the html code*/

            $( "#dialog-form-html" ).dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                height: 600,
                width: 400,
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                    Cancel: function() {
                        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                    }
                },
                close: function() {
                }
            });

            $( "#get-html" )
            .button()
            .click(function() {
                var allContent = "";
                allContent += "--Column 1-- <br />"
                $("#col1 .portlet").each(function(i,element){
                    allContent += $(this).find(".portlet-header").text() + ": " + $(this).find(".portlet-content").text() + "<br />";                          
                });
                allContent += "<br /><br />--Column 2-- <br />"
                $("#col2 .portlet").each(function(i,element){
                    allContent += $(this).find(".portlet-header").text() + ": " + $(this).find(".portlet-content").text() + "<br /><br />";                          
                });
                allContent += "<br /><br />--Column 3-- <br />"
                $("#col3 .portlet").each(function(i,element){
                    allContent += $(this).find(".portlet-header").text() + ": " + $(this).find(".portlet-content").text() + "<br /><br />";                          
                });
                allContent += "<br /><br />--Column 4-- <br />"
                $("#col4 .portlet").each(function(i,element){
                    allContent += $(this).find(".portlet-header").text() + ": " + $(this).find(".portlet-content").text() + "<br /><br />";                          
                });

                $( "#dialog-form-html" ).html(allContent);
                $( "#dialog-form-html" ).dialog( "open" );
            });
```